# Flight cancellation refund not received after 6 months. What to do?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, eu, refunds, air-france

I am not sure if this question fits this forum. I made a booking for a flight from Amsterdam to Lyon in July 2023. I booked the ticket on Air France's website. I was assigned a booking number, but not a ticket. Immediately following the payment, I was notified that my flight was cancelled. I booked an alternate flight on a different carrier, which proceeded smoothly. However, I still haven't received a refund of the cancelled ticket. I am at my wits' end trying to figure out how to get my money back. It has been well over 5 months, and everytime I call Air France enquiring about the matter, I am stalled and given hilariously different answers to my question of when I can expect any progress on the matter.

Three months into the sordid saga, I was informed over email that the money has been refunded, but I don't see the money in my account. I have been telling Air France customer executives the same everytime I call them, and I still don't see the money. Is there any EU body or a national body I can complain to regarding this? Or is there anything else I can do before I contact a lawyer?

Comment: In which country do you reside?

Comment: As quick: check https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm . They have also a list of national aviation authorities in case things are not proceeding well (but also it provides much more information).

Comment: Note: refund may be given to the credit card account used for the booking, so you will not see in your account, but possibly as credit in the credit card (and in such case you may ask them for the refund)

Comment: @jcaron I reside in Germany.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I made the payment through bank transfer. Thus, I am pretty sure the money has not reached my account.

Comment: Ok. It was to be sure. In any case, my link should provide links to national authorities where you can complain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Air France paid the amount after some escalation. Not sure what the issue was, but happy to receive my money back.

EDIT: The issue was the money was marked as a "floating amount" by my bank due to reasons that I fully did not understand. I had to call my bank with the transaction number Air France finally gave in my most recent call (sometime in the first week of March) and asked my bank to confirm a transaction with this transaction number. I did not have to escalate the matter.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. It might be useful for others if you'd amend your answer (using the "Edit" button below the text) to explain what "some escalation" actually was.